# How to fix 'X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array' error on sklearn fit_transform?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, data-science

```
R&D Spend   Administration  Marketing Spend State   Profit
0   165349.20   136897.80   471784.10   New York    192261.83
1   162597.70   151377.59   443898.53   California  191792.06
2   153441.51   101145.55   407934.54   Florida 191050.39
3   144372.41   118671.85   383199.62   New York    182901.99
4   142107.34   91391.77    366168.42   Florida 166187.94
5   131876.90   99814.71    362861.36   New York    156991.12
6   134615.46   147198.87   127716.82   California  156122.51
7   130298.13   145530.06   323876.68   Florida 155752.60
8   120542.52   148718.95   311613.29   New York    152211.77
9   123334.88   108679.17   304981.62   California  149759.96
10  101913.08   110594.11   229160.95   Florida 146121.95
11  100671.96   91790.61    249744.55   California  144259.40
12  93863.75    127320.38   249839.44   Florida 141585.52
13  91992.39    135495.07   252664.93   California  134307.35
14  119943.24   156547.42   256512.92   Florida 132602.65
15  114523.61   122616.84   261776.23   New York    129917.04
16  78013.11    121597.55   264346.06   California  126992.93
17  94657.16    145077.58   282574.31   New York    125370.37
18  91749.16    114175.79   294919.57   Florida 124266.90
19  86419.70    153514.11   0.00    New York    122776.86
20  76253.86    113867.30   298664.47   California  118474.03
21  78389.47    153773.43   299737.29   New York    111313.02
22  73994.56    122782.75   303319.26   Florida 110352.25
23  67532.53    105751.03   304768.73   Florida 108733.99
24  77044.01    99281.34    140574.81   New York    108552.04
25  64664.71    139553.16   137962.62   California  107404.34
26  75328.87    144135.98   134050.07   Florida 105733.54
27  72107.60    127864.55   353183.81   New York    105008.31
28  66051.52    182645.56   118148.20   Florida 103282.38
29  65605.48    153032.06   107138.38   New York    101004.64
30  61994.48    115641.28   91131.24    Florida 99937.59
31  61136.38    152701.92   88218.23    New York    97483.56
32  63408.86    129219.61   46085.25    California  97427.84
33  55493.95    103057.49   214634.81   Florida 96778.92
34  46426.07    157693.92   210797.67   California  96712.80
35  46014.02    85047.44    205517.64   New York    96479.51
36  28663.76    127056.21   201126.82   Florida 90708.19
37  44069.95    51283.14    197029.42   California  89949.14
38  20229.59    65947.93    185265.10   New York    81229.06
39  38558.51    82982.09    174999.30   California  81005.76
40  28754.33    118546.05   172795.67   California  78239.91
41  27892.92    84710.77    164470.71   Florida 77798.83
42  23640.93    96189.63    148001.11   California  71498.49
43  15505.73    127382.30   35534.17    New York    69758.98
44  22177.74    154806.14   28334.72    California  65200.33
45  1000.23 124153.04   1903.93 New York    64926.08
46  1315.46 115816.21   297114.46   Florida 49490.75
47  0.00    135426.92   0.00    California  42559.73
48  542.05  51743.15    0.00    New York    35673.41
49  0.00    116983.80   45173.06    California  14681.40
```

code

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
ct = ColumnTransformer([('State', OneHotEncoder(), [3])], remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X), dtype=np.float)
```

I keep getting an error like -

```
TypeError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-17f64bed7e4c> in <module>
      3 
      4 ct = ColumnTransformer([('State', OneHotEncoder(), [3])], remainder='passthrough')
----> 5 X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X), dtype=object)

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    516         self._validate_remainder(X)
    517 
--> 518         result = self._fit_transform(X, y, _fit_transform_one)
    519 
    520         if not result:

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in _fit_transform(self, X, y, func, fitted)
    446             self._iter(fitted=fitted, replace_strings=True))
    447         try:
--> 448             return Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
    449                 delayed(func)(
    450                     transformer=clone(trans) if not fitted else trans,

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1002             # remaining jobs.
   1003             self._iterating = False
-> 1004             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1005                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1006 

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    833                 return False
    834             else:
--> 835                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    836                 return True
    837 

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    752         with self._lock:
    753             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 754             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    755             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    756             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    207     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    208         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 209         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    210         if callback:
    211             callback(result)

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    588         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    589         # arguments in memory
--> 590         self.results = batch()
    591 
    592     def get(self):

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
    253         # change the default number of processes to -1
    254         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 255             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    256                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    257 

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    253         # change the default number of processes to -1
    254         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 255             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    256                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    257 

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    726     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    727         if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 728             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    729         else:
    730             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    370         """
    371         self._validate_keywords()
--> 372         return super().fit_transform(X, y)
    373 
    374     def transform(self, X):

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    569         if y is None:
    570             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 571             return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    572         else:
    573             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py in fit(self, X, y)
    345         """
    346         self._validate_keywords()
--> 347         self._fit(X, handle_unknown=self.handle_unknown)
    348         self.drop_idx_ = self._compute_drop_idx()
    349         return self

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py in _fit(self, X, handle_unknown)
     72 
     73     def _fit(self, X, handle_unknown='error'):
---> 74         X_list, n_samples, n_features = self._check_X(X)
     75 
     76         if self.categories != 'auto':

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py in _check_X(self, X)
     41         if not (hasattr(X, 'iloc') and getattr(X, 'ndim', 0) == 2):
     42             # if not a dataframe, do normal check_array validation
---> 43             X_temp = check_array(X, dtype=None)
     44             if (not hasattr(X, 'dtype')
     45                     and np.issubdtype(X_temp.dtype, np.str_)):

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    506     if sp.issparse(array):
    507         _ensure_no_complex_data(array)
--> 508         array = _ensure_sparse_format(array, accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
    509                                       dtype=dtype, copy=copy,
    510                                       force_all_finite=force_all_finite,

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in _ensure_sparse_format(spmatrix, accept_sparse, dtype, copy, force_all_finite, accept_large_sparse)
    304 
    305     if accept_sparse is False:
--> 306         raise TypeError('A sparse matrix was passed, but dense '
    307                         'data is required. Use X.toarray() to '
    308                         'convert to a dense numpy array.')

TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.....

Comment: What is `X` in `ct.fit_transform(X)`?

Comment: In above dataset X = dataset[:,:-1].values

Comment: There's something wrong with that `X`, that doesn't fit the expectations of `fit_transform`.  SInce I can't recreate it, I'm not going dig further.  You need to check things like it's shape, and dtype, and match that with the `fit` docs.

Comment: `fit` thinks `X` might be a scipy.sparse` matrix, but that is probably a fallback, having failed other tests.

Comment: Have you tried the advice already offered in the message itself, i.e. `Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array`?

Answer (score 2):

You can set `sparse_threshold=0`, not very sure about the rest of your code, what X is etc:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder 
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer                                           
import pandas as pd                                                                     
import numpy as np   

X = pd.DataFrame({"R&D":[1,2,3,4],
"State":["New Tork","Florida","New York","California"]}) 

ct = ColumnTransformer([('State', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], 
sparse_threshold=0,remainder='passthrough')
np.array(ct.fit_transform(X[['State']]), dtype=np.float)

array([[0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```